# How to clear the serial buffer of Raspberry Pi

Tags: serial

I use MATLAB to control the serial communication of Raspberry Pi, but its communication frequency is too fast, and the serial buffer is easily full. I want to know how to clear the serial buffer?
Here is my code:

```
    r = raspi;
pc = serialdev(r,'/dev/serial0',9600,8,'none',1);
pc.Timeout = 5;
out = 0;
data1 = xlsread('data.xlsx',1);
tou = interp1(0:3600:23*3600,data1,0:1:24*3600-1,'spline')';
tou = [tou;tou];
load('electricity_price.mat');
money = money/0.58*0.86;
price = [0:24*3600-1;kron(money,ones(1,3600))]';
price = [price;price];
while true
    try
        data = read(pc,2,'int32');
        if length(data) > 0
            Troom = double(data(1))/1000;
            t = double(data(2));
            tout = tou(t+1:900:t+6*900);
            P = price(t+1:900:t+6*900,2);
            out = look(Troom, tout,P);
        end
        write(pc, out, 'int8');
        pause(0.1)
    catch
        disp('NOT COMPUTE')
    end
end
```

There is no problem with the connection, but now that the buffer is full, I cannot continue reading or writing